# How to initialize ApolloClient in SvelteKit to work on both SSR and client side

Tags: apollo, svelte, sveltekit

I tried but didn't work. Got an error:  Error when evaluating SSR module /node_modules/cross-fetch/dist/browser-ponyfill.js:

```
<script lang="ts">
import fetch from 'cross-fetch';
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache, HttpLink } from "@apollo/client";

const client = new ApolloClient({
    ssrMode: true,
    link: new HttpLink({ uri: '/graphql', fetch }),
    uri: 'http://localhost:4000/graphql',
    cache: new InMemoryCache()
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With SvelteKit the subject of CSR vs. SSR and where data fetching should happen is a bit deeper than with other somewhat "similar" solutions. The bellow guide should help you connect some of the dots, but a couple of things need to be stated first.

To define a server side route create a file with the `.js` extension anywhere in the `src/routes` directory tree. This `.js` file can have all the import statements required without the JS bundles that they reference being sent to the web browser.

The `@apollo/client` is quite huge as it contains the `react` dependency. Instead, you might wanna consider importing just the `@apollo/client/core` even if you're setting up the Apollo Client to be used only on the server side, as the demo bellow shows. The `@apollo/client` is not an ESM package. Notice how it's imported bellow in order for the project to build with the node adapter successfully.

Try going though the following steps.

1. Create a new SvelteKit app and choose the 'SvelteKit demo app' in the first step of the SvelteKit setup wizard. Answer the "Use TypeScript?" question with `N` as well as all of the questions afterwards.

```sh
npm init svelte@next demo-app
cd demo-app
```

2. Modify the `package.json` accordingly. Optionally check for all packages updates with `npx npm-check-updates -u`

```json
{
    "name": "demo-app",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "svelte-kit dev",
        "build": "svelte-kit build --verbose",
        "preview": "svelte-kit preview"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@apollo/client": "^3.3.15",
        "@sveltejs/adapter-node": "next",
        "@sveltejs/kit": "next",
        "graphql": "^15.5.0",
        "node-fetch": "^2.6.1",
        "svelte": "^3.37.0"
    },
    "type": "module",
    "dependencies": {
        "@fontsource/fira-mono": "^4.2.2",
        "@lukeed/uuid": "^2.0.0",
        "cookie": "^0.4.1"
    }
}
```

3. Modify the `svelte.config.js` accordingly.

```js
import node from '@sveltejs/adapter-node';

export default {
    kit: {
        // By default, `npm run build` will create a standard Node app.
        // You can create optimized builds for different platforms by
        // specifying a different adapter
        adapter: node(),

        // hydrate the <div id="svelte"> element in src/app.html
        target: '#svelte'
    }
};
```

4. Create the `src/lib/Client.js` file with the following contents. This is the Apollo Client setup file.

```js
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
import { ApolloClient, HttpLink } from '@apollo/client/core/core.cjs.js';
import { InMemoryCache } from '@apollo/client/cache/cache.cjs.js';

class Client {
    constructor() {
        if (Client._instance) {
            return Client._instance
        }
        Client._instance = this;

        this.client = this.setupClient();
    }

    setupClient() {
        const link = new HttpLink({
            uri: 'http://localhost:4000/graphql',
            fetch
        });

        const client = new ApolloClient({
            link,
            cache: new InMemoryCache()
        });
        return client;
    }
}

export const client = (new Client()).client;
```

5. Create the `src/routes/qry/test.js` with the following contents. This is the server side route. In case the graphql schema doesn't have the `double` function specify different query, input(s) and output.

```js
import { client } from '$lib/Client.js';
import { gql } from '@apollo/client/core/core.cjs.js';

export const post = async request => {
    const { num } = request.body;

    try {
        const query = gql`
            query Doubled($x: Int) {
                double(number: $x)
            }
        `;
        const result = await client.query({
            query,
            variables: { x: num }
        });

        return {
            status: 200,
            body: {
                nodes: result.data.double
            }
        }
    } catch (err) {
        return {
            status: 500,
            error: 'Error retrieving data'
        }
    }
}
```

6. Add the following to the `load` function of `routes/todos/index.svelte` file within `<script context="module">...</script>` tag.

```js
    try {
        const res = await fetch('/qry/test', {
            method: 'POST',
            credentials: 'same-origin',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                num: 19
            })
        });
        const data = await res.json();
        console.log(data);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
```

7. Finally execute `npm install` and `npm run dev` commands. Load the site in your web browser and see the server side route being queried from the client whenever you hover over the `TODOS` link on the navbar. In the console's network tab notice how much quicker is the response from the `test` route on every second and subsequent request thanks to the Apollo `client` instance being a singleton.

Comment: thanks!, the imports didnt really work for me like you had them. I simply have `import { ApolloClient, HttpLink, InMemoryCache } from "@apollo/client/core";`

Answer (score 0):

Two things to have in mind when using phaleth solution above: caching and authenticated requests.

Since the client is used in the endpoint /qry/test.js, the singleton pattern with the caching behavior makes your server stateful. So if A then B make the same query B could end up seeing some of A data.

Same problem if you need authorization headers in your query. You would need to set this up in the setupClient method like so

```js
setupClient(sometoken) {
  ...

  const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
    return {
      headers: {
        ...headers,
        authorization: `Bearer ${sometoken}`
      }
    };
  });

  const client = new ApolloClient({
    credentials: 'include',
    link: authLink.concat(link),
    cache: new InMemoryCache()
  });
}
```

But then with the singleton pattern this becomes problematic if you have multiple users.

To keep your server stateless, a work around is to avoid the singleton pattern and create a `new Client(sometoken)` in the endpoint.

This is not an optimal solution: it recreates the client on each request and basically just erases the cache. But this solves the caching and authorization concerns when you have multiple users.

Comment: In that kind of scenario I'd recommend switching from the `@apollo/client/core` package to the `@urql/core` package as `urql` holds onto the client instance by itself. The `urql` API is not that different from `apollo`'s. In case you're interested have a look at their [addAuthToOperation](https://formidable.com/open-source/urql/docs/advanced/authentication/#configuring-addauthtooperation).